Can user-run apps access all items in the user's home directory?
As I understand it, an application run by a user will typically inherit the file-access permissions of the user who ran it.
Presumably this means that all user applications on, for example, desktop Ubuntu, can access the contents of .ssh including private keys.
Am I right about that and, if so, what solutions exist to improve security for partially-trusted apps?

You can look at thing like apparmor, selinux and other Linux MAC security systems. In any case, ssh private keys are usually (and should be) encrypted.

If i understood it right, you ask how to run applications you do not trust without let them access your full $HOME.
Based on the privileges you have there are some options. This or that you look for sand boxing, there are several options, like (not complete list):

containers
filesystem namespaces
application restrictions, e.g. flatpak, appamor
chroot
alternative accounts

This or that way the question is how you share the data you would like to share with the application in a convenient way.
So just one example (alternative accounts):

user main(uid=1000,gid=1000) data to share: /home/main/data
user test(uid=1001,gid=1001,1000) data: /home/test/data -symlink2-> /home/main/data
permission of /home/main like u+rwx,g=x,o-rwx
permission of /home/main/data like u+rwx,g+rwx,o-rwx,+s
assuming test has a umask of 7

assuming you have sudo configured that main is allowed to become test:
sudo -u test -i <untrusted-application-to-start>

so the app would run as test and can access the shared data.
Some stuff is remaining based on the application, like X-access, sound-access, ... (here maybe a system like flatpak + flatseal does it better out-of-the-box, but only if your application is available in this ecosystem)

You're right a user who runs a program will have access to all files and directories in ~/ directory of that user, according to file system permissions.
However your concern is .ssh directory:

Presumably this means that all user applications on, for example,
desktop Ubuntu, can access the contents of .ssh including private
keys.

The .ssh directory must not contain any private keys, only public keys should be present and trusted hosts file.
Private SSH keys should be kept in key ring of the ssh daemon.
Several methods (including automated) exist to access private keys stored that way.
Same applies to any other similar credentials, they should not be stored anywhere in your ~/ directory but should be managed by applications that manage credentials in a secure manner.
As to what solutions exist to improve security of partially-trusted apps, I'd say, don't use software you don't trust and limit them to those available in distro's repository.
edit:
This is addition as suggested in comment section regarding private ssh key...
Secure storage of SSH private keys can be done by various software which depends on Desktop Environment or OS Distribution.
KDE Users have pre-installed software called kdewallet (Wallet Manager) which is used to securely store credentials including private SSH key decryption password.
To add existing private ssh key to ssh-agent we normally do:
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/private_key
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key

And then to auto load the private key from kdewallet on login to KDE desktop we do:
Create login script as follows:
nano ~/.ssh/ssh-add.sh

Put the following contents into:
#!/bin/bash
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ksshaskpass
ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key

Replace /usr/bin/ksshaskpass with the output of which ksshaskpass and if there is no output
install ksshaskpass with sudo apt install ksshaskpass and try again.
Replace private_key with your SSH private key file name which is to be added.
chmod your script with chmod 500 ~/.ssh/ssh-add.sh and chmod +x ~/.ssh/ssh-add.sh to make it read-only and executable for yourself.
In System Settings head to Startup and Shutdown -> Autostart and add this script there as "login script".
Log out and log in again, fire up terminal and run ssh-add -l to verify it works.
The benefit of this approach is you don't need to type-in password to decrypt your private ssh key every time you log-in, the decrypt password is stored in kdewallet.
Unfortunately this means you can't have the private key removed from ~/.ssh directory, but improved security is that you don't have to type decryption password for ssh key every time, avoiding possibility of keylogger stealing your password either by typing or by stealing it from clipboard.
You can still however have your key on USB and reconnect it every time prior login.

ssh-keygen stores private keys in ~/.ssh by default. Where do you suggest users store them? Or should everyone use only hardware keys?

@StephenKitt No, once you do ssh-add the keys are put into key ring, after that you should delete private keys from ~/.ssh directory and store them on external disk away from computer for backup purpose.

You should add that to your answer — the question specifically asks for solutions to improve security, but your answer only says “yes, you should, there are ways to do so” without going into detail. (Won’t your approach require reconnecting the external disk every time the system boots? I use hardware keys so I’m not familiar with the impact of removing private keys.)

@StephenKitt You're right, my mistake, private key can't be deleted from ~./ssh but non the less I provided sample instructions that I believe are more secure than typing password each time.
